# Close subnav once a different subnav is open with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Currently I have this working almost perfectly, but the user has the ability to open multiple sub-nav's at once, and I need any open sub-nav's to close when another one is open.

Basically, the jQuery that's beloe, I need to classes to be removed if a new sub-nav is clicked on, currently it only removes them if the same one is clicked.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="st-menu" id="menu-4a">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Guidance Manual</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Resource Directory</a><div class="toggle-arrow"><img src="/assets/images/chevron-up-solid.svg"/></div>
            <ul class="reg-subnav">
                <li><a href="#">Stormwater Plan Review Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pilot Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Proprietary Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Additional Resources</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Stormwater 101</a><div class="toggle-arrow"><img src="/assets/images/chevron-up-solid.svg"/></div>
            <ul class="reg-subnav">
                <li><a href="#">Regulations</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stormwater Management</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stormwater Billing & Retrofits</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Green City, Clean Waters</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a><div class="toggle-arrow"><img src="/assets/images/chevron-up-solid.svg"/></div>
            <ul class="reg-subnav">
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Development Review Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".toggle-arrow").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').find(".reg-subnav").toggleClass('open-sub');
    $(this).closest('li').find('.arrow-image').toggleClass("flip"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use siblings and select the elements with the class and remove them.

```js
$("nav").on("click", ".toggle-arrow", function(){
    var currentLi = $(this).closest('li')
    currentLi.find(".reg-subnav").toggleClass('open-sub');
    currentLi.find('.toggle-arrow').toggleClass("flip");
    
    //clean up the other open elements
    var otherLis = currentLi.siblings()
    otherLis.find(".open-sub").removeClass('open-sub')
    otherLis.find(".flip").removeClass('flip')

});
```

```css
.reg-subnav {
  display: none;
}

.reg-subnav.open-sub {
  display: block;
}

img {
 width: 20px;
}

.toggle-arrow {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.toggle-arrow img {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transition: transform 0.75s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.toggle-arrow.flip img {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="st-menu" id="menu-4a">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Guidance Manual</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Resource Directory</a><div class="toggle-arrow"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/120/120906.svg"/></div>
            <ul class="reg-subnav">
                <li><a href="#">Stormwater Plan Review Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pilot Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Proprietary Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Additional Resources</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Stormwater 101</a><div class="toggle-arrow"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/120/120906.svg"/></div>
            <ul class="reg-subnav">
                <li><a href="#">Regulations</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stormwater Management</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stormwater Billing & Retrofits</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Green City, Clean Waters</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a><div class="toggle-arrow"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/120/120906.svg"/></div>
            <ul class="reg-subnav">
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Development Review Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this one? You should remove class 'open-sub' from all of lists.

```
$(".toggle-arrow").click(function(){
    $("nav.st-menu").find(".reg-subnav").removeClass('open-sub');
    $(this).closest('li').find(".reg-subnav").toggleClass('open-sub');

    $("nav.st-menu").find(".arrow-image").removeClass('flip');
    $(this).closest('li').find('.arrow-image').toggleClass("flip"); 
});
```

Comment: This does seem to work almost perfectly, but the only flaw here is now that if you open a sub-nav, and then try to close it by clicking the same one, nothing happens, any thoughts? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Needs to ignore the current element

Answer (score 1):

Could be done with [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

```js
$(".toggle-arrow").click(function(){
    $(".reg-subnav").not($(this).closest("li").find(".reg-subnav")).removeClass("open-sub");
    $(this).closest('li').find(".reg-subnav").toggleClass('open-sub');
    $(this).closest('li').find('.arrow-image').toggleClass("flip"); 
});
```

And you could clean up your code even more by using the [siblings selector](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```js
$(".toggle-arrow").click(function(){
    $(".reg-subnav").not($(this).siblings(".reg-subnav")).removeClass("open-sub");
    $(this).siblings(".reg-subnav").toggleClass('open-sub');
    $(this).siblings('.arrow-image').toggleClass("flip"); 
});
```

**EDIT:**
Per @epascarello, This could also be made more performant by storing the subnav so it's not queried for twice:

```js
$(".toggle-arrow").click(function(){
    var $thisSubnav = $(this).siblings(".reg-subnav");
    $(".reg-subnav").not($thisSubnav).removeClass("open-sub");
    $thisSubnav.toggleClass('open-sub');
    $(this).siblings('.arrow-image').toggleClass("flip"); 
});
```

Comment: I would clean it up with `var currentLi = $(this).closest('li')` so you are not looking it up 3 times.

Comment: After using siblings, there are only 2 lookups, so it doesn't quite violate the rule of 3's, but yes!  I'll make an edit.

Comment: That seems to be working better, but the flip class is not being added here. Apologies for any confusion, still a beginner here lol